# send message stream to view using express js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have the following nodejs/express js

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  socket.on(channelName, message => { 
    //console.log(channelName, message);
  });

  res.render('index', {page:message, menuId:channelName});
});
```

How can I pass the `message` it was the real time data to display in `index` view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the route method, you will need to fire/emit the event, so for example 
 
when a message hit this route all the listeners on the 'message' 
 will call the Action :

```
app.post('/messages', (req, res) => {
  var message = new Message(req.body);
  message.save((err) =>{
    if(err)
      sendStatus(500);
    io.emit('message', req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  })
})
```

And in the client side script tag in index.html, add the following code:

```
var socket = io();

socket.on(‘message’, addMessages)
```

Comment: can you help to show me the full of your explaination @Nasr

Comment: check this article 
https://dev.to/captainpandaz/a-socket-io-tutorial-that-isn-t-a-chat-app-with-react-js-58jh 
you need to understand the cycle of the message and request